# Languages translation using reactjs & reflux

Tags: reactjs, translate, refluxjs

I am new to reactJS, I am working on a web app to make it multilingual, so I am looking for any library which handles translation in ReactJS (similar to angular-translate).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.bebetterdeveloper.com/coding/getting-started-react-flux.html) you can find one of multiple approaches you have to make your app in ReactJS multilingual. Right now is one which I use in my projects.